# How to recover a gzipped .bed file in its original format

Tags: python, gzip

```
   import gzip#compresses the .bed example file
   input_file = open("example.bed","rb")
   data = input_file.read()
   #convert_data = bytearray(data)
   with gzip.open("example.bed.gz", "wb") as filez:
        filez.write(data)
   filez.close()

   #failed attempts
   with gzip.open("example.bed.gz", "r+") as fileopen:
   output=fileopen.read()
   output
   print(output)
   
   #this works but not in the desired manner
   import pandas as pd
   df=pd.read_csv("example.bed.gz", delimiter='\t',header=1 )
   df.to_csv('exampleziptotxt.bed', index=False)
```

format before gzipping='chr8\t59420123
format from opening and reading gzipping=b'chr8\t59420123\

I have tried decoding to utf-8 only to get a bytes conflict

The above script gzips a tab delimited .bed file, I would like to unzip it and get the original .bed file in the exact same format prior to gzipping (e.g. just reversing the gzipping). Any advice on how to accomplish this would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the error message? Any traceback?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the error message **with full traceback**.

Comment: What do you mean by "exact"? Since you put it in quotes, it is natural to read this to mean something else than the actual meaning of *exact*.

Comment: In order to get any response to your question, you need to add what you tried that didn't do what you want, and what _exactly_ it is that you want. How did it get comma delimited in the first place? A .bed file is not comma delimited. You are showing reading a .bed file in your question, which would be white-space delimited, and would still be white-space delimited upon decompression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   import pandas as pd file
   df=pd.read_csv("example.bed.gz", delimiter=',',header=0 )
   df.to_csv('exampleziptotxt.bed', index=False)
```

I only needed to adjust the delimiter from "\t", to "," and it restores the original format